# Access 2010 Cannot share database across network

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a 2010 Microsoft Access database in the format FixList.accdb
There is one table and one form in it, that i want a small number of users to access at the same time.
I have split the database, so that the back end is in a different folder to the front end.
Finally, i have gone to options and selected the following:
 - Default Open Mode =Shared
 - Default Record Locking = No locks
 - Open Databases by using record-level locking (NOT ticked)

It opens fine when 1 user opens the database, but when a second user double clicks the Access file to open, the following message appears. "You do not have exclusive access to the database at this time. If you proceed to make changes, you may not be able to save them later".   My question is, what other change(s) can i make to this database so that the error message above does not appear when more than one person opens the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT have more than one concurrent user open the same copy of the front-end (e.g., by having all users open the copy from a folder on the server). Each user **must** have their own local copy of the front-end .accdb/.accde file.